# Looking at a grade data, with student names, grades and credit hours to order data based on either gpa, credit hours, or names

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am reading the data from a text file and would like order the data by gpa.  I wrote the following code

```
import string  

def main() :
my_list = []
# open the input file for reading
filename = raw_input("Enter name of the grade file: ")
infile = open(filename, 'r')
print infile 
# process subsequent lines of the file
for line in infile :
    name, hours, qpoints = line.split('\t')
    gpa = float(qpoints)/float(hours)
    my_tuple = (name, gpa)
    print name, gpa 
    my_list += my_tuple
data = sorted(my_list, key = lambda x: gpa)


if __name__ == '__main__' :
    main()
```

I get an error in `main()`  I find that  the 'line.split('\t') does not give the output that I expect. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I thought, that I would get the first part working before I tried to add the camparison  function  cmpGpa  Thank you for your help.

Comment: You say the output is "incorrect." exactly what output do you get and how does it compare to the expected output?

Comment: Just a note that you can do `infoStr.split('\t')` instead of `string.split(infoStr,'\t')`

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten the parantheses after the function calls in `new_id = (st.getName, st.getGpa)`. Change that to `new_id = (st.getName(), st.getGpa())`, and I think you'll be better off.

---

The code concerning `st = makeStudent(line)` does not seem to be problematic - I would guess that there are some problems with your input file. Try to print each line and see if the output is as expected. If this seems ok, try to print the variables after splitting the line, and see if it's like you want. You'll probably find a tiny bug somewhere.

---

A couple of other things that you may consider:

- Using `key` to sort your data is easier and [faster](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) (see note 8) than `cmp`, and is the [preferred way](http://regebro.wordpress.com/2009/09/28/use-key-when-sorting-not-cmp/) of sorting lists since Python 2.4.
- In your case, `sorted(your_list, key=lambda x: x.getGpa())` will sort a list of Student instances based on their gpa.
- If the gpa value is static (`hours` and `qpoints` don't change), you should consider calulating the gpa in `__init__`. Why would you want to recalculate it each time you access it? If `hours` or `qpoints` may change after initialization, you may be better of making some `set_variable` methods that updated the gpa after setting the new value.
- Get rid of your `get_variable_name` methods in your `Student` class unless you have a good reason to implement them. As the code stands now, I don't see the need for them, simply access the variables directly.

Comment: Thank you all,for your response.  @ValekHalfHeart, I had added a lot of print statements to the code, it does not end up splitting the string into the three parts.  I get an output that does not make sense to me.  It is <open file 'data6.txt', mode 'r' at 0x02585180>
<__main__.Student instance at 0x02F3D350>
<bound method Student.getName of <__main__.Student instance at 0x02F3D350>> <bound method Student.getGpa of <__main__.Student instance at 0x02F3D350>> and each line is the same as the first one repeated the n times (n # of students in the list).

Comment: @SteinerLima  I followed your suggestion and got rid of the Student class.

Comment: @SteinerLima I did not see your comment till I had made the changes.the code still does not work, am I using the sorted function correctly?

Comment: No, use `lambda x: x[1]`